# MVCSiteMapProvider and adding Registered Trademarks to pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVCSiteMapProvider (https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for my breadcrumb solution in MVC ASP.NET. Does anyone have experience with adding `&reg;` to their breadcrumbs when using MVCSiteMapProvider? `&reg;`is not valid to use in the title attribute in XML. For our branding we have to have the registered mark after some of the page names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `&reg;` with `&#174;` and your XML should be valid

Comment: thanks, I always forget about the alternative way of writing those.